# Carregamento de pagina Ajax + Jquery + Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Opa, boa tarde galera sou um pouco novo em rails e to com uma pequena dificuldade. Tenho um formulario de login (sessions/new) e um formulario de cadastro (users/new), em cada um desses formularios, tenho um link no qual ao ser clicado redireciona o usuario para o outro formulario. Gostaria de fazer isso via Ajax + Jquery, pra ficar uma transição mais suave. Porem nunca usei ajax no rails. Se alguem puder me dar uma luz sobre o que fazer agradeço, um tutorial, ou uma dica de como proseguir. Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Funciona do mesmo modo como em qualquer outra linguagem, não tem segredo. Você faz a requisição via Ajax a informa aonde você quer que o resultado dessa requisição seja exibido

Comment: Então, fiz aqui, porem parece que só um link funciona. Retirei o require turbolinks pra testar e só um funciona sem refresh. Acredito que seja algum erro bobo meu. link: http://pastebin.com/VUqxNype

Comment: Faça um grande favor e coloque o código que você julgar necessário na sua pergunta, assim fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso você está utilizando duas actions de dois controllers diferentes, portanto você será redirecionado de uma para a outra atravéz de um redirect_to após a criação da session.

Pelo que entendi você não deseja um redirecionamento, e sim que um form aparece na mesma tela após a criação do outro, portanto, deixe os dois forms em uma mesma action, após o envio dos dados de um, esconda-o e mostre o outro.

Em uma action você pode ter instâncias para os dois forms, enquanto o post feito em ajax, tenha actions diferentes:

```
RegistrationsController
    def new
      @session = Session.new
      @user = User.new
    end
end

Class SessionsController
    def create
      #create session here
    end
end

Class UserController
   def create
     #create user here
   user
end
```

Na view de seus forms você terá as requisições ajax:

```
#views/registrations/new.html.erb

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/sessions/create",
  data: { "email": "email@email.com", "password": "password" }
});

$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "/user/create",
  data: { "name": "Adolph", "las_name": "Schindler" }
});
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta, deu pra entender bem da forma que voçe explicou. Acabei usando a gem nprogress, não era exatamente o que precisava mas ta quebrando um galho. Vou fazer uns testes dessa maneira que voce disse, pra ver como fica. Obrigado pela resposta.